# Why I'm getting KeyError when the column exists?

Tags: python, pandas, json-normalize

Using json_normalize I created a dataframe, the data I parsed includes a list of dictionaries, hence I used the parameters "record_path" and "meta".

The issue is that I get a KeyError when a calling a column (that exists) from the dataframe.

The column exists, in fact I do .columns it prints, but when I call it, it throws the error.

I'm using Pandas:1.3.5

```
audiences = response['audiences']        
audiences_df =pd.json_normalize(response['audiences'],
record_path=['fees'], meta=['audience_id ','audience_name '], errors='ignore')

print(audiences_df.columns)
print(audiences_df["audience_id"]
```

The response I get is

```
          if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'audience_id'
```

Comment: I do not see the actual names of all columns in the question, include that information verbatim as printed.

Comment: The `meta` argument has an extra space at the end of each column name.

Answer (score 1):

The KeyError you're encountering is likely because of the extra spaces in the meta parameter.
try this instead

```
meta=['audience_id','audience_name']
```

Comment: you're totally right, such a obvious answer!! thanks